# Complex sql, get rows only if date is older and group by 3 columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I was wondering if this query if possible. I have this table:

```
+----+-------+--------+--------+------------+
| id | plate | agency | status |  assigned  |
+----+-------+--------+--------+------------+
|  1 | UB10  |      0 |      3 | 2010-01-02 |
|  2 | UB10  |      2 |      2 | 2010-01-03 |
|  3 | UB10  |      5 |      1 | 2010-01-04 |
+----+-------+--------+--------+------------+
```

In this way everything is OK and I use all the records. The main issue is the following situation:

```
+----+-------+--------+--------+------------+
| id | plate | agency | status |  assigned  |
+----+-------+--------+--------+------------+
|  1 | UB12  |      0 |      3 | 2010-01-02 |
|  2 | UB12  |      2 |      1 | 2010-01-03 |
|  3 | UB12  |      5 |      2 | 2010-01-04 |
+----+-------+--------+--------+------------+
```

I need a sql query where I'm able to skip the records with the status = 1 only if I have records with the same plate and there is a newest record with different status. In the above example I only need the first and third record.

It's possible?

Thanks very much.

*EDITED FOR GRAMMAR*

Comment: Is it that you want the record where Status=1 AND any records that have an `Assigned' date greater than that record?

Comment: this is not english: `get the rows with status = 1 if have this row is the last inserted` -- what do you mean.  Are you saying you ignore items with status = 1 if there is another of the same plate with a later date?

Comment: Sorry for the grammar (I edited the question). And YES Hogan, I need the skip the records if the status is equal to 1 and the plate is the same. If the last record status is 1, then I need to include it in the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do this with a prepared statement like so

```
SET @sql = "CREATE VIEW v_test AS (SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE status <> 1)";
SET @union = " UNION (SELECT * FROM my_table ORDER BY assigned DESC LIMIT 1)";

SELECT @final := case status WHEN 1 then CONCAT(@sql, @union) ELSE @sql END 
FROM
(   SELECT status 
    FROM my_table
    WHERE id =
    (   SELECT id FROM my_table 
        ORDER BY assigned DESC LIMIT 1
    )
) t;

PREPARE stmt FROM @final;
EXECUTE stmt;
SELECT * FROM v_test;
```

[**DEMO WHERE LAST ROW HAS STATUS <> 1**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fb5e9/2/4)

[**DEMO WHERE LAST ROW HAS STATUS = 1**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/484d6/1)

[**DEMO WITH A VIEW**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fb5e9/3)

Comment: Um, not working. I'm not getting the records with the status equal to 1. Thanks John.

Comment: @noisedan if the last row has a status = 1 then it'll add that last row if its not then it wont. isnt that what you want?

Comment: Yes, it's seems to be working. For a weird reason SequelPro is not returning the complete rows after I increment the available records. Just one thing, is there any chance to make it a view? I'm not sure if this is possible. Thanks!

Comment: @noisedan yes it is possible.. I just edited my answer with a working solution as well as the select from the view with appropriate results.

Comment: @noisedan if it solves your issue can you please mark it as accepted? it would be greatly appreciated :)